# DotNetNuke Find all Pages with specific text

Tags: sql, dotnetnuke

I have a DNN 6 installation (soon to be DNN7) and I need to update every page that links to a specific page to a new page... I can write that query, but I'd like to see a list of the actual pages that will be updated.. I have this so far:

```
select t.TabName -- Some sorcery to get page name --
from HtmlText h
join Modules m on h.ModuleID=m.ModuleID
join TabModules tm on m.ModuleID=tm.ModuleID
join Tabs t on tm.TabID=t.TabID

where Content like '%MyTextToFind%'
```

This query returns all the tabs that have the text, but not the actual pages that contain the text.

How do I get the actual pages?  (page path would be wonderful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tools that will do this, if you check out the Engage F3 module from http://www.engagesoftware.com/Products/DNN_Modules/Engage_F3.aspx you can get a free download that will search/replace text across all HTML modules.

disclaimer: I wrote the original version of F3 many years ago, but am no longer an employee of Engage, and haven't been involved in the most recent releases of the module

UPDATE: To get the actually URL of the page you will likely need to go outside of SQL, due to the way URLs are handled in DotNetNuke. If you really want to generate a URL in SQL though you can create non-friendly one with something like

```
select t.TabName,
'http://MYWEBSITE.com/default.aspx?tabid=' + Cast(t.TabID as varchar) 
from HtmlText h
join Modules m on h.ModuleID=m.ModuleID
join TabModules tm on m.ModuleID=tm.ModuleID
join Tabs t on tm.TabID=t.TabID
```

That will generate a "nonfriendly" url which will work, but obviously doesn't have the page name. If you are using the standard HumanFriendly format in DNN you could try taking the "TabPath" column on Tabs and use that to build the URL by adding .aspx to the end, removing the double slashes, and putting the domain name on the front.

Comment: I'm really looking for just a SQL solution.  I'm sure it's possible, I'm just not sure of the tables i have to join

Comment: The source for F3 is available from Engage as well. Your question really isn't a question though either, what problem is coming from executing that query

Comment: Question added.. (:  I'll take a look at the source.

Comment: Updated the answer with more info

Comment: Rats... that's what I was afraid of... ok.. good enough.  thanks